# trivial for-loop needs an explanation

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Since `i += i` is an abbreviation for `i = i + i`, the following code

```
for (var i = 0; i<=10; i++) {
console.log(i += i) }
```

should output:

```
1. 0, because  0 += 0 + 0 (i = 0)
2. 2, because  0 += 1 + 1 (i = 2)
3. 6, because  2 += 2 + 2 (i = 6)
4. 12, because 6 += 3 + 3 (i = 12)
```

However, although the console does output the values of 1. - 3., namely, 0, 2, and 6, correctly, the value that I get for 4., which is 14, is not the value that I predicted (the lines 1. - 4. above were typed out before the for-loop was executed) the for-loop would output (=`12`). 
What am I interpreting wrong here?

The code itself is evidently uninteresting, but nonetheless I am curious why it works the way it does.

Comment: don't forget that `i++` increments `i` one more each time, its not a different var from the `i` inside the loop.

Comment: I think the OP is perfectly aware of this...until the fourth iteration. I don't know why everyone's posting so many details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are updating `i` inside the loop as well as for the loop itself. This means you need to look at both updates to see what really happens to `i`. Here are the steps unrolled:

```
for(var i=0; i<=10; i++){ ...

// i = 0 here
console.log(i += i);
// logged 0 += 0 (0)
// now i will be incremented to 1
console.log(i += i);
// logged 1 += 1 (2)
// increment i to 3
console.log(i += i);
// logged 3 += 3 (6)
// increment i to 7
console.log(i += i);
// logged 7 += 7 (14)
// increment i to 15
// ... etc
```

It looks like you just missed the fact that `+=` is also updating the `i` inside the loop, not just from the `++` incrementor.

Comment: Just the explanation I was looking for. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

So basically, you are adding one then double the number in each iteration, starting with 0.

Then you should get: 0, 2, 6, 14. I think your math, not code, is wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that `for` loops have four parts: Initialiation, Test, Body, and Increment.

...and they work like this:

1. Initialization
2. Test, jump to after loop if test is false*
3. Body
4. Increment
5. Go to step 2

So, here's the way that loop works:

1. (Initialization) `i = 0`
2. (Test) Since `0` is `<= 10`, keep going
3. (Body):

   1. Evaluate `i += i`: Since `i` is currently `0`, `i = 0 + 0` is `i = 0`.
   2. Log that
4. (Increment) Evaluate `i++`. Since `i` is `0`, it becomes `1`
5. (Test) Since `1` is `<= 10`, keep going
6. (Body):

   1. Evaluate `i += i`: Since `i` is currently `1`, `i = 1 + 1` is `i = 2`
   2. Log that
7. (Increment) Evaluate `i++`. Since `i` is `2`, it becomes `3`
8. (Test) Since `3` is `<= 10`, keep going
9. (Body):

   1. Evaluate `i += i`: Since `i` is currently `3`, `i = 3 + 3` is `i = 6`
   2. Log that
10. (Increment) Evaluate `i++`. Since `i` is `6`, it becomes `7`
11. (Test) Since `7` is `<= 10`, keep going
12. (Body):

    1. Evaluate `i += i`: Since `i` is currently `7`, `i = 7 + 7` is `i = 14`
    2. Log that
13. (Test) Since `14` is **not** `<= 10`, stop

---

* "Test, jump to after loop if test is false" Technically, not just false, but anything *falsey*, which is `0`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, `""`, or of course, `false`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what your code does:

```
1. i starts with 0, then you assign to it 0 + 0. console logs i as 0
2. i increments to 1, then you assign to it 1 + 1. console logs i as 2
3. i increments to 3, then you assign to it 3 + 3. console logs i as 6
4. i increments to 7, then you assign to it 7 + 7. console logs i as 14
```

Note that `i += i` is not the same as `i += i + i`, but as `i = i + i`. It is an assignment, and the value returned is the new value of `i`.